# how do you make emacs-w32 display utf-8 characters?

Tags: fonts, utf-8, emacsw32

I have used emacs as my primary editor for a while. Since I now have a windows dependency at work I tried installing `emacs-w32`. I am having problems making it display utf-8 characters correctly. The problem is discussed in detail in [this github issue](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/issues/211#issuecomment-68825163) but can be seen in this picture

[image: font problem]

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Comment: Sounds like you should switch to a font which has glyphs for the characters you want to see.

Comment: @tripleee you're right, I posted an answer to the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @tripleee points out in the comments, the solution is to change to a font that can render these glyphs. An example solution is below, taken from [here](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/commit/b2c33fe58ec2b3f6115b1fb13e6b688fb7a0b6d9) and modified to remove unnecessary information:

```
(let ((font "Source Code Pro"))
(when (member font (font-family-list))
  (pcase window-system
    (`x (message "nothing to do"))
    (`mac (message "nothing to do"))
    (`w32 (let ((fallback-font "MS Gothic:mono"))
               ;; window numbers
               (set-fontset-font "fontset-default"
                         '(#x2776 . #x2793) fallback-font nil 'append)
               ;; mode-line circled letters
               (set-fontset-font "fontset-default"
                         '(#x24b6 . #x24fe) fallback-font nil 'append)
               ;; mode-line additional characters (i.e. golden ratio)
               (set-fontset-font "fontset-default"
                         '(#x2295 . #x22a1) fallback-font nil 'append)))
    (other (message "nothing to do")))))
```